# "JavaScript required" error when opening an Excel sheet from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, error, excel

I have created a SharePoint website with a document library to allow my team members to share Excel files more easily.

When they open Excel sheets, they are redirected to the Excel client app since their documents use a lot of macros and have protection incompatible with the Web App.

This works just fine for the majority of users including me. However, some team members get the error below.
[image: JavaScript Required JavaScript is required. This web browser does not support JavaScript or JavaScript in this web browser is not enabled. To find out if your web browser supports JavaScript or to enable JavaScript, see web browser help.]

This error appears inside their Excel client app.

For some users, everything works fine. For others, Internet Explorer works and Chrome doesn't. And for some, both Internet Explorer and Chrome do not work.

We all have the same settings because our browsers, Excel client app and Windows are managed by our organisation.

I have tried to reproduce the error by disabling my JavaScript, but SharePoint do not work at all when doing so. I have also tried to reset my browser settings.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: When you write "Excel client app" do you mean the desktop Excel program? Can your customers download the sheet and then open it from the File >> Open dialog? What version of Excel? The error would seem to indicate that Excel is trying to launch an embedded web page or component from within the sheet. Are there any?

Comment: Yes the Excel program / Yes they can open it from the File -> Open, but they get the same error or the sheet is empty / Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus / It's trying to launch our organisation authentication page for some reason even it's not embedded in the sheet.

Comment: New question: does this happen with all Excel sheets, or only some?

You say that all your users have the same settings, but that is not (in my experience) always the case even when settings are centrally managed. Is your SharePoint site in the trusted list for all users? Have you had the affected users log out of their O365/Microsoft accounts, clear their cookies, and log in again? One long-shot idea I would try in your position: can these users edit the spreadsheets if they log in from a different computer?

Comment: We have done more tests and this only happens with some specific Excel Sheets. They can open other .xlsx and .xlsm, but not the one that they need. Also, they can download the document, edit it and reupload it (we use this as a temporary solution). They cannot edit it directly from SharePoint. Besides, the last person that reuploaded the file (and everyone who never had this issue) can edit it directly from SharePoint without getting the error. The others need to do the temporary solution. I think there might be a security setting or a connection problem that I am not awared.

Comment: **UPDATE:** Unfortunately, we never found the origin of the problem nor understood why some users had the bug while others were fine. However, we figured out that it wasn't a problem with Sharepoint; it was either caused by our authentification system (ADFS) or Office. Since it wasn't an issue with Sharepoint, I am not the one who worked on the fix, but I think they reinstalled Office and that fixed the issue in most cases. Sorry if that is not the answer you're looking for.